# Vectores en C++

Tags: array, vectores

estoy haciendo un ejercicio en C++ para que se muestren los elementos de un arreglo en orden descendente, sin embargo al querer correr el programa me aparecen unas letras y números extraños. Adjunto código y captura de pantalla.

/* Mostrar elementos de un arreglo de manera inversa*/

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include<conio.h>

 using namespace std;

int main(){

int numeros[5]={1,2,3,4,5};  

  for(int i=4;i>=0;i--){
  
      cout<<numeros<<endl;
  
  }




   getch();
   return 0;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: debes colocar `numeros[i]`

Comment: `numeros` es un arreglo. Los arreglos decaen en punteros. Lo que estás viendo es la dirección de memoria del primer elemento. Para acceder a un elemento del arreglo lo haces como te dijo Christian.

Comment: @Christian gracias, ya me funciona

Comment: @Mateo cierto, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Te traigo la respuesta:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int numeros[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};

    for(int i=4;i>=0;i--){
        cout<<numeros[i]<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Recuerda que estás utilizando un for y dentro de él un iterador inicializado en el valor 4 (int i=4), de la siguiente forma mostrará los elementos de forma descendente.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funcionó